# Strange Select Option Behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I am building a site and am having problems with select options not showing and I am not too sure what is going on.

For example, I have this page: http://bit.ly/182gqK9

If you click on the "Choose an area..." select dropdown you will see 3 options, the third is slightly cut off for some reason (not sure why that is), but if you look in the source there is clearly 6 options...

```
<select id="area" name="attribute_area">
    <option value="">Choose an area...</option>
    <option value="Area 2">PO1 - PO9</option>
    <option value="Area 1">PO12 - PO17</option>
    <option value="Area 2">SO14 - SO19</option>
    <option value="Area 2">SO30</option>
    <option value="Area 1">SO31</option>
</select>
```

I disabled JavaScript in FF and it seems to fix the issue, but if I remove all scripts from the page, the problem persists.

I also have a similar equally strange issue on this page: http://bit.ly/1aMTMJY

With that page, if you click on the select, it shows 4 options, if you click off it and back onto it, it displays 5 options. When again there are in fact 6 options.

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome and Firefox for me on Mac

Comment: yea I am on ie 8 right now on my work computer and everything looks fine.

Comment: I see what you mean, and yes, it is odd. What happens if you disable just the event handler defined on the `option` elements? (Circa `$('#area').children('option')`…)

Comment: I am on a Win7 PC and have just tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE9 and am still having the same issues. Although on the second page, it displays 5 options instead of 4 then 5 when I click back on it. I have never experienced an issue like this before!

Comment: @JordanGray even if I remove/comment out that part, nothing changes :(

Comment: Okay, scratch my (just now deleted) comment about not seeing it, I was clicking on the second link instead of the first. Definitely seeing it in Chrome 31 and Canary 33.

Comment: @JordanGray, thanks for the response. Just to confirm, when clicking on the first link you are seeing all 6 options? I have even tested on my iPhone and only 3 options are displaying for the first link.

Comment: @StuartTaylor-Jones No, I had just clicked on the wrong link. I saw only some of the items, with one partially visible. Which is really, *really* odd—WebKit specifically ensures that [popup menus only ever show whole menu items](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/e8b995ee86a842e2366ef5ea235da64beaa288a4/Source/WebCore/platform/win/PopupMenuWin.cpp#L336). Even if you fix this, it would be cool if you could trim it down to a minimum test case, as this seems to be a WebKit bug.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your JavaScript is dynamically removing options from the select. When I disable JavaScript, I see the list of 6 options shown in your question. When I enable JavaScript and inspect the HTML, this is what I see:

```
<select id="area" name="attribute_area">
    <option value="">Choose an area...</option>
    <option value="Area 2" class="active">PO1 - PO9</option>
    <option value="Area 2" class="active">SO14 - SO19</option>
    <option value="Area 2" class="active">SO30</option>
</select>
```

Do you have code somewhere that updates the list of options on the fly?

The fact that disabling JS fixes the problem means that JS must be causing the problem. You say that you still see the problem even when you remove all JS from the page. What happens if, after removing all the JS, you also disable JS in the browser?

If all the JS has truly been removed, then disabling it should have no effect. On the other hand, if disabling it still fixes the problem, then there must be JS still hanging around somewhere - perhaps because the JS is being cached.

You say that you don't have any code that is explicitly trying to update the options on the fly, but perhaps some code is doing this inadvertently or indirectly.

Comment: Hi dshiga, thanks for the response. There is some JS that handles events on the select, but nothing that updates the options on the fly. Even if I remove all the JavaScript from the page, the problem still persists.

Comment: Sure, no problem! I still think JS *must* be removing options somehow.  Otherwise, why would disabling JS fix the problem? Is there any chance there is some JS that you overlooked when you tried to remove it all? Also, what happens if you remove all JS, then *disable* JS? If there's no JS left, then disabling JS should have no effect.

Comment: @Stuart I'm strongly inclined to agree with @dshiga; I checked in the inspector yesterday and the options are disappearing from the generated DOM when they're plainly there in the original source. There's some JS tomfoolery going on here, I'm just not sure where.